# How do you convert large hexadecimal values to decimal values in R when passing a vector with missing values?

Tags: r

In R you can use the `strtoi()` function to convert a hexadecimal value to a decimal value,

```
strtoi(c("14A", "15", NA_character_), 16L)

# [1] 330  21  NA
```

But when you provide more digits then the strtoi function starts to overflow and returns NA instead of the converted value.

```
strtoi(c("49EA72A5000"), 16L)

# [1] NA
```

The `Rmpfr::mpfr()` function appears to be able to handle larger output values

```
Rmpfr::mpfr(c("49EA72A5000"), base = 16)

# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  44   bits 
# [1] 5079455911936
```

but it does not handle missing character values very well and throws an error when the missing value is now part of the vector.

```
Rmpfr::mpfr(c("49EA72A5000", NA_character_), base = 16)

# Error in if ((base == 2 && any(i <- tolower(substr(x, 1L, 2L)) == "0b")) ||  : 
# missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

The function does appear to handle the logical missing value

```
Rmpfr::mpfr(NA, base = 16)

# 1 'mpfr' number of precision  2   bits 
# [1] NaN
```

Is there another package in R that converts large digit hexidecimal values to decimal values and has appropriate error handing? The output does not need to be an integer but could be numeric or character.

Or is there an option that can be passed to the `mpfr()` function to change how it deals with missing values?

Comment: Please do submit a bug report to `bug.report("Rmpfr")` so that the issue can be solved rather than worked around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make your own wrapper for appropriate missing value handling. For instance:

```
mpfr_na <- function(x, base)
{
  x[is.na(x)] = NaN
  Rmpfr::mpfr(x, base = base)
}

mpfr_na(c("49EA72A5000"), base = 16)
# [1] 5079455911936

mpfr_na(c("49EA72A5000", NA_character_), base = 16)
# [1] 5079455911936           NaN

mpfr_na(c("49EA72A5000", NA), base = 16)
# [1] 5079455911936           NaN

mpfr_na(c("49EA72A5000", NaN), base = 16)
# [1] 5079455911936           NaN
```

Does this solve your issue?

Answer (score 2):

naive approach in base R

```r
strtol = function(x, base) {
  if (base != 16L) stop("strtol supports only base=16")
  if (length(x) > 1) stop("strtol support scalar input only")
  x = as.character(x)
  ans = strtoi(x, base)
  if (!is.na(ans)) return(ans)
  xx = rev(strsplit(x, split="", fixed=TRUE)[[1L]])
  s = 0.0
  for (i in seq_len(length(xx))) {
    s = s + as.numeric(strtoi(xx[i], base)) * (16L^(i-1L))
  }
  s
}
format(strtol("49EA72A5000", 16L), sci=F)
#[1] "5079455911936"
```

- handles `NA`
- handles values bigger than int32 range
- not vectorized, unlike `strtoi`

Comment: This is a great start. I think this can be generalized to handle arbitrary sizes. Or maybe I am wrong in assuming that eventually this will not be precise?

Comment: it will not be precise after some big values. This was enough for me for the moment so I stick to that.

Comment: Might I suggest the following: `s = sum(16L^(seq_len(length(xx)) - 1L) * strtoi(xx, base))`. Or you could simply remove the assignment (i.e `s = `) and just leave the expression as the last line.